# Node js express\ react js cors issue

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

I'm dealing with an issue with CORS in express js, so the issue is that when I use the CORS Library I receive cors header normally without a problem in postman as shown in the image below [postman response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vwae.png)

But when I call the same api from my React js I get a cors error and there is no header for cors in the response headers.

Second issue is that when I use cors library in my main app like so :

[code of server.js using CORS in App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUrvZ.png)

My whole express server just doesn't return anything for a very long time .

Here is the relevant code in express js :

```
//server.js

  const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const app = express();



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const dbConfig = require('./config/database.config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(()=>{
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now ...',err);
    process.exit();
    
})

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
res.json({"message" : "Welcome to EasyNotes application. Take notes quickly. Organize and keep track of all your notes."});
});

require('./app/routes/note.routes.js')(app);

app.listen(3000,() => {

    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
    
})
```

This is my routing js file

```
//routing

const cors = require('cors');
module.exports = (app) => {

    const notes = require('../controllers/note.controller.js');

    app.post('/notes', cors(), notes.create);

    app.get('/notes', cors(), notes.findAll);

    app.get('/notes/:noteId', cors(), notes.findOne);

    app.post('/notes/:noteId', cors(), notes.update);

    app.delete('/notes/:noteId', cors(), notes.delete);


}
```

What is most weird is that I'm using the same api but a different route and its working fine in the browser, like when I use this route :

```
 app.get('/notes', cors(), notes.findAll);
```

it works fine.

please help !!

Answer (score 0):

From reading your post, I'm not sure you completely understand what is CORS and why the issue is triggered. I recommend you take a look at the [Mozilla explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

To explain it a little further, the browser probably does an `OPTIONS` request to your API to check if Cross origin requests are allowed. To do this, you need to use the `cors` package just as you show in the second screenshot you attached.
You mention that your app does not work when you do this, and this is probably the bug you should be investigating, maybe in [the github issues of the package](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues).

Finally, I never used `cors()` as you're using it in your routing file, just including the middleware as you do in the screenshot should be enough, Maybe this is the cause of the second issue you mention?

Good luck with it

Answer (score 0):

in you `server.js` file you are using `app.use(cors)` but it should be `app.use(cors())`. Here is an example from one of my projects that I'm currently working on

```
require('./db')

const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const postRouter = require('./routes/post')

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use('/api', postRouter)

/*
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    
    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names);
    });
})
*/
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(200)
})


app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server started on port 5000"));
```